# Reporting progress without losing too much performance

Tags: python

So, this is a sort of general question that I've been thinking about for a while. When doing big simulations I find that it helps me a lot to know how my simulation is doing (how far it's gotten etc).

Right now I'm doing this by including an integer when calling the function that tells the program how many times it's supposed to report its progress, however this makes the run take like 40 % longer.

What I'm doing is something like:

```
.... # calling and setting up the function here, 
# the int is called "reportProgress"

for i in range(n):
..... # the simulation here

    if reportProgress != 0:
                fraction = int(n / reportProgress)
                if i % fraction == 0:
                    numerator = int(i / fraction)
                    if stopPrint == False:
                        print(message) # the message tells us how we're doing
```

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this? Because while this does the job, it's really calculation heavy!

Comment: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

Comment: https://tqdm.github.io/

Comment: Whoops, beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can move repeating `fraction` calculation out of loop body:

```
report_every = n // report_progress

for i in range(n):
    ... # the simulation here

    if i % report_every:
        print('{} out of {}'.format(i, n))
        # one-line writing
        # sys.stdout.write('\r{} out of {}'.format(i, n))
```

if it still too slows try decreasing number of reports

as mention in comments you can use `tqdm` package:

```
from tqdm import tqdm 

for i in tqdm(range(n), miniters=report_every): 
    # simulation step
```